# Jagged appearance of lines in 3D plot

Tags: graphics3d

I wanted to know if there's a simple way to plot some field lines of a 3D vector field, something like an extension of [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html). I've searched for a while, but haven't found anything "standard".

So I tried, in the meanwhile to use a more artificial way to get to the result I was seeking for, namely, plotting separately every field line:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {
  {u, E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, -E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, 2 E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, -2 E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, 0, -2 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0, 2 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0, E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0, -E^(u/8)}
  , {u, E^(u/8), E^(u/8)}
  , {u, -E^(u/8), -E^(u/8)}
  , {u, E^(u/8), -E^(u/8)}
  , {u, -E^(u/8), E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0.5 E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, -0.5 E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, 1.5 E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, -1.5 E^(u/8), 0}
  , {u, 0, -1.5 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0, 1.5 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0, 0.5 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0, -0.5 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0.5 E^(u/8), 0.5 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, -0.5 E^(u/8), -0.5 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, 0.5 E^(u/8), -0.5 E^(u/8)}
  , {u, -0.5 E^(u/8), 0.5 E^(u/8)}
  }
 , {u, 0, 15}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
 , PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.003]}
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> False
 , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y^2 + z^2 <= 9]
 ]
```

Now I have another problem. Here is what I obtain from the code above:

[image: figure]

Is there a way to make those lines look smoother?

Comment: I tried your code, and your lines look reasonably smooth to me. Can you post a picture of your result to see what you get?

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D[
 Table[{u, k E^(u/8), p E^(u/8)}, {k, -2, 2, .5}, {p, -1.5, 
    1.5, .5}], {u, 0, 15}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.003]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y^2 + z^2 <= 9]]` is much shorter

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @MarcoB Agree.Those lines are as good as they come

Comment: Thank you for posting the picture. Within *Mathematica*, go to the menu Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics, and try increasing the Antialiasing to the max setting. This is what I get: [plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch6Yp.png)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's definitely what i was looking for, that thing was driving me crazy!

Comment: @MarcoB - what if setting the anti-aliasing to the highest level still gives crappy lines?   http://i.imgur.com/NkrW3gG.png